# For what paths is resolvingSymlinksInPath() wrong?

Tags: macos, symlink, nsurl, foundation

On macOS, /tmp is a symlink to /private/tmp, yet when I do this:

```
URL(fileURLWithPath: "/tmp").resolvingSymlinksInPath().path
```

it returns `"/tmp"`.

(I've reported this to Apple, and they closed it as a duplicate, so they know about it already.)

Is it publicly known what paths have incorrect values returned by this method?  If it's just a couple paths which are hardcoded internally, then it'd be easier to check for them, than to rewrite a working resolvingSymlinksInPath() from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation for `resolvingSymlinksInPath`:

> If the name of the receiving path begins with /private, this property strips off the /private designator, provided the result is the name of an existing file.

So if the result is, say, `/private/var` and there is `/var` then that is what is returned.

This appears to be based on a convention only, there is no check that the resultant path references the same filesystem item. E.g. create `/a`, `/private/a` and sym link `/test` to `/private/a` then resolve symlinks for `/test` and the result is `/a` despite that not being the same as `/private/a`

Comment: Ah!  That's on NSURL -- I was checking the docs for NSString, which have an older identical similarly named method, which doesn't have this information (but still has this behavior).

Comment: That's a great clue, but I'm not sure that it describes all existing behavior.  In my example, the receiver is "/tmp", which doesn't begin with "/private".  It's also stripping "/private" from the return value.

Comment: Agree that Apple's language isn't the best here but they do mean what you are seeing. Maybe "If the resolved path begins with..." would be better language.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not seeing it.  In Apple's documentation, "receiver" always means the object that is being sent the message, and "return value" is the result: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html

Comment: In any event, what I'm getting from this is that it's impossible to write a correct version of resolvingSymlinksInPath() using Foundation's resolvingSymlinksInPath(), because that can convert paths to other paths which bear no relation to the original.

Comment: Ok try "If the *resolved* name of the receiver...". As to "correct version" the intent is clearly to make `/private` off limits, a mere shadow of a ghost, and what is returned here is the, by definition, direct path to the object and you can use it as such. Maybe some other reader will know the history of this imperfect illusion, if you wish to break it use the calls in section 2 of `man` to do so. HTH

Comment: I know why `/private` exists: it's a vestigial directory from NeXTstep's net booting feature.  I'd be fine with maintaining the illusion, if it worked, but macOS tries to maintain at least 3 different false illusions of parts of the filesystem these days, and they don't always play well together.